# .NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC

Tags: c#, performance

I'm testing an app that reads thousands of small objects and sends then back to the client through remoting.

Using ProcessExplorer from SysInternals I see the ".NET CLR Memory\% Time in GC" is bigger than 50% under heavy load.

- Does it mean 50% or even more of the time is being spent on the GC?
- If so, how can I improve performance? An obvious answer is: not creating so many objects but, how can I do that? Would "structs" work better?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating this objects? Are you creating a few at a time, over and over and over, or are you creating thousands at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Value types are put on the stack, reference types are put on the heap. Once you go "out of scope" releasing value types (i.e. structs) is a lot faster than releasing objects on the heap (these are GC-ed).

About the %time in GC, take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2005/05/06/415296.aspx)

Hope this helps.